# Is retro Lode Runner available on any modern system?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, lode-runner

I'd like to play Lode Runner again. How can I do this on a modern system?

I'll settle for any reasonable clone, but only if it **does not scroll**. I downloaded the NES version on Wii Virtual Console, and it scrolls! This is not the real Lode Runner.

By modern system, I mean PC (including web-based) & the current generation of consoles (Jan 2011).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about looking on [virtualapple.org](http://www.virtualapple.org/loadrunnerdisk.html)?

Comment: This looked promising, but the controls weren't mapped very well - it's not very obvious how to play.

Comment: i'd recommend downloading the emulator...controls are far more intuitive...and you can download the disk image directly from the site (i had the same issue you did with the controls)

Comment: This worked for me. I can't say the controls were intuitive, but I did work them out, and I successfully played a few games :-)

Comment: now if only i had an old apple joystick to use...:D

Comment: loderunner was fine with the keyboard. motion was with j,k,l, and i; dig was u and o, but the thing i can never remember, when firing up the emulator, is the ctrl-key sequences to get it started, skip levels, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the Xbox Live Arcade remake of Lode Runner? Not sure whether it locks scrolling, but it appears to be quite close to original version.

You might also look for Lode Runner: The Legend Returns, a 1994 DOS game that might be fully playable using DOSBox (version 0.65), or Lode Runner 2, a 1998 Windows release - they seem to be available on eBay (not sure whether it will be happy with Vista/7 though).

--- EDIT

Just learned about an improved version of Lode Runner: The Legend Returns, namely the Lode Runner Online: Mad Monks' Revenge, a 1995 game for Windows 95. The best thing about it is that although it had been commercially available, it was released as freeware and can be freely downloaded from [its official webpage](http://www.daggert.net/Folio/Programming/Presage/LodeRunner/Loderunner1.htm).

Comment: eBay might be good as a last resort. I don't own an XBox, so XBLA isn't an option.

Comment: As for the 'no scrolling' requirement - just watched few videos on YT ad it seems the Lode Runner 2 features an isometric, pseudo-3D levels, which are I believe quite different from the original. On the other hand, Lode Runner: The Legend Returns levels seem to fully fit on screen, so no scrolling should be involved.